# textmate >> vim for python - teething troubles: especially indenting

Tags: python, vim, textmate, macvim

I'm (attempting) to move from textmate to vim [macvim to be exact] as my primary editor. I have already installed snipmate - wondering if there are other plugins you would suggest I install?

In particular I seem to be having a lot of trouble with indenting (`<<` seems to really do some very strange/unpredictable things), and I can't seem to find a solution for this - are there plugins I need for this to work properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For source code,

```
:h =
```

In a nutshell, in normal mode inside a block you wish to work with:

- `=a{` to re-indent a block. `=a}` and `=aB` work as well.
- `=2a{` to re-indent this block and its outer block.
- If you happen to stand on a brace then `=%` will re-indent up to the matching brace.
- `>a{` to increase the indent of this block.
- `<a{` to decrease the indent of this block.
- `.` repeats the last command, so `<a{.` decreases the indent of this block twice.

Make sure you have `filetype` set so Vim recognizes the filetype. Indenting is a function of the file type, after all.

### For text,

```
:h gq
```

- gq{ will format this paragraph.
- gq( will format this sentence.
- gqgq will format this line.
- gggqG will format the entire document.

Comment: can you be more specific on an appropriate workflow? let's say to deindent a block?

Comment: By the way, I see you're a python guy. In Python indents take part in semantics and program logic. Vim doesn't program for you. Sometimes it can see that a certain range of lines must be at least indented in a certain way for the program to be valid while pretty. But in Python you often need to further indent with the `<` and `>` commands to tune the semantics of things.

Comment: For example, in Python, `if True: \ndothis() \ndothat()` can mean different things depending on the indent. (imagine `\n` to be a newline). Should `dothat()` be part of the `if` block, or of the outer block? Vim can't answer that, but it can tell for sure that `dothis()` should be indented for the program to be valid. It will leave `dothat()` unindented for you to decide in what scope it should be.

Answer (score 2):

Set the filetype setting in your vimrc file

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

That should enable filetype plugins and automatic indentation

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you need exactly as I have not used textmate. But I do use these [**Plugins for VIM**](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/vim-plugins-surround-vim). They have helped me a lot.